# Pegar valor do input para o AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

Encontrei um código que envia uma informação via AJAX, porém preciso que, além de enviar esta informação, ele também envie o `value` de um outro campo(`input`).
Preciso ler o `value` do `input name` conforme esta no `ajaxpro.php`.

**index.php**

```
<form action="ass.php" id="form" method="post">
    <label for="nome"> Nome </label>
    <input onkeydown="mascaraNome( this )" onkeyup="mascaraNome( this )" name="nome" type="text" placeholder="Nome" size="30"/><br/><br/>
    <label for="funcao"> Função </label>
    <input onkeydown="mascaraFuncao( this )" onkeyup="mascaraFuncao( this )" name="funcao" type="text" placeholder="Função" size="30"/><br/><br/>
    <label for="telefone"> Telefone </label>
    <input onkeydown="mascaraTel( this )" onkeyup="mascaraTel( this )" name="telefone" id="telefone" type="text" placeholder="Telefone" size="30"/><br/><br/>
    <label for="email"> E-mail </label>
    <input onkeydown="mascaraEmail( this )" onkeyup="mascaraEmail( this )" name="email" type="text" placeholder="E-mail" size="30"/><br/><br/>
    <label for="cel"> Celular </label>
    <input onkeydown="mascaraCel( this )" onkeyup="mascaraCel( this )" name="cel" type="text" placeholder="Celular" size="30"/><br/>                                
    <input type="checkbox" name="whats"> Possui Whatsapp?<br/>
    <label for="filial"> Filial </label><br/>
    <select name="filial" required>
        <option value="" disabled selected>Seleciona a filial...</option>
        <option value="piracicaba">Piracicaba</option>
        <option value="botucatu">Botucatu</option>
        <option value="lencois">Lençóis Paulista</option>
        <option value="jau">Jaú</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    </div>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" hidden><br/><br/>
</form>
</div>      
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3" style="padding-top:30px;">
        <strong>Select Image:</strong><br/>
        <input type="file" name="upload" id="upload"><br/>
        <button id="testinho" class="btn btn-success upload-result" name="testinho" id="testinho">CONFIRMAR RECORTE</button><br/><br/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
        <div id="upload-demo" style="width:350px"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4" style="">
        <div id="upload-demo-i" style="background:#e1e1e1;width:150px;padding:30px;height:150px;margin-top:30px"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<button type="submit" style="float: right;" onClick="submitform()" class="btn btn-success upload-result" /> CRIAR ASSINATURA </button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

**Script js**

```
$uploadCrop = $('#upload-demo').croppie({
    enableExif: true,
    viewport: {
        width: 100,
        height: 100,
        type: 'circle'
    },
    boundary: {
        width: 150,
        height: 150
    }
});

$('#upload').on('change', function () { 
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (e) {
        $uploadCrop.croppie('bind', {
            url: e.target.result
        }).then(function(){
            console.log('jQuery bind complete');
        });
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
});

$('.upload-result').on('click', function (ev) {
    $uploadCrop.croppie('result', {
        type: 'canvas',
        size: 'viewport'

    }).then(function (resp) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/assinatura/ajaxpro.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {"image":resp},
            success: function (data) {
                html = '<img src="' + resp + '" />';
                $("#upload-demo-i").html(html);

            }
        });
    });
});
```

**ajaxpro.php**

```
<?php
$data = $_POST['image'];
$teste = $_POST['name']; // PRECISO RECUPERAR DADOS DESTE CAMPO !!!!!

list($type, $data) = explode(';', $data);

list(, $data)      = explode(',', $data);

$data = base64_decode($data);

$imageName = time() . '.png';

file_put_contents('upload/'.$imageName, $data);

?>
```

Comment: Coloque no `data` o valor do input: `data: {"image":resp, "name": $("#name").val()}`

Comment: deu certo, valeu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está enviando no AJAX apenas o valor de `image` no campo `data`. Para enviar outro valor basta acrescentar ao objeto do `data` outra chave com o nome de `name` e o valor do campo `input#name`:

```
data: {"image":resp, "name": $("#name").val()}
```

O `$("#name").val()` irá capturar o valor do `input#name` e enviar junto no POST.